# How does getopt::long work with ntermixed long/short options?

Tags: perl

The Getopt description says that both '-' and '--' are accepted for the same option, and that short options can be bundled. Assuming that "help" is an option then:

```
script --help     # succeeds
script --h        # succeeds
script -h         # fails
```

If we have two or more options with unique first characters ("ab", "cd") the -ac does not work but --a and --c does. I have looked at all the getopt options and I thought used them correctly. Am I missing an option or have I misunderstood the getopt description?

The actual code is:

```
      Getopt::Long::Configure ( "gnu_getopt"
                              , "auto_abbrev"
                              , "bundling"
                              , "ignore_case_always"
                              );

      GetOptions ( 'normalize'   => \$normalize
                 , 'exclude=s'   => \@exclude
                 , 'help'        => \$help
                 , 'include=s'   => \@include
                 , 'recurse'     => \$recurse
                 , 'update'      => \$update
                 , '2update'     => \$update2
                 , 'copy'        => \$copy
                 , 'move'        => \$move

                 , 'n'           => \$normalize
                 , 'e=s'         => \@exclude
                 , 'h'           => \$help
                 , 'i=s'         => \@include
                 , 'r'           => \$recurse
                 , 'u'           => \$update
                 , '2'           => \$update2
                 , 'c'           => \$copy
                 , 'm'           => \$move
                 );
```

With the repeated getopts parameter allowing recognition of both "-h" and "--h". With the duplicated options things seem to work as expected, but my reading of the getopt description seems to say that the repeated code is not necessary.

Comment: Can't reproduce ... I declare `$help` and then options with names `h` and `help`, both setting `$help`, and another short option (`v`) and it all works as expected.  Invocations with `--help` and `--h` and `-h` work, as well as bundling `-hv`.  (And it doesn't let me do `-help`, just as documented.)

Comment: (Why is that `gnu_getopt` set along with other config that it is a shorthand for...?)

Comment: Tip: There's no point in parsing further options when help is requested, so calling a function that exits (using `=> \&help`) makes more sense

Comment: @ikegami: thanks. Didn't think to use \@func. Good tip.

Comment: @zdim: I thought the documentation does say that "-help" is valid. Is this what you meant?

 "gnu_getopt" is shorthand for "gnu_compat, bundling, permute, no_getopt_compat" all of which are useful.

Comment: zdim was pointing out there's no point in using both `gnu_getopt` and `bundling` since the former subsumes the latter

Comment: As for invocation `script -help`, with bundling that would mean `script -h -e -l -p`, since long options must have `--` so the `-` implies that what folloows is (all, bundled) short options; thus that should fail.  It's got to be `--help` (with bundling).

Answer (score 3):

With `bundling`, `--` *must* be used for long option. `-` can only be used for short options, of which you defined none.

You can disable bundling (`nobundling` after `gnu_getopt`, instead of `bundling` which is already enabled by `gnu_getopt`).

```
use Getopt::Long qw( );

for (
   [qw( --help )],
   [qw( --h )],
   [qw( -h )],
) {
   @ARGV = @$_;
   say "@ARGV";

   Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( gnu_getopt nobundling auto_abbrev ignore_case_always ));
   Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
      'normalize' => \my $normalize,
      'exclude=s' => \my @exclude,
      'help'      => \my $help,
      'include=s' => \my @include,
      'recurse'   => \my $recurse,
      'update'    => \my $update,
      '2update'   => \my $update2,
      'copy'      => \my $copy,
      'move'      => \my $move,
   );

   say $help // "[undef]";
}
```

Or you can use `help|h` defining a long (`--`) and a short (`-`) option in one go.

```
use Getopt::Long qw( );

for (
   [qw( --help )],
   [qw( --h )],
   [qw( -h )],
) {
   @ARGV = @$_;
   say "@ARGV";

   Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( gnu_getopt auto_abbrev ignore_case_always ));
   Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
      'normalize|n' => \my $normalize,
      'exclude|e=s' => \my @exclude,
      'help|h'      => \my $help,
      'include|i=s' => \my @include,
      'recurse|r'   => \my $recurse,
      'update|u'    => \my $update,
      '2update|2'   => \my $update2,
      'copy|c'      => \my $copy,
      'move|m'      => \my $move,
   );

   say $help // "[undef]";
}
```

Both programs output the following:

```
--help
1
--h
1
-h
1
```

Comment: Superb answer. But the documentation says in perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html we have "In the default configuration, options names may be abbreviated to uniqueness, case does not matter, and a single dash is sufficient, even for long option names." I think that the documentation is wrong although your answer is right. Any way to address the documentation?

Comment: You're not using there default configuration. Enabling `bundling` changes that, as documented, and as I said

Answer (score -2):

```
GetOptions(
    'path|p=s'  => \$opt{path},
    'help|h'    => \$opt{help},
    'man|m'     => \$opt{man},
    'debug|d'   => \$opt{debug}
) or pod2usage(2);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: @Igor F -- it all described in the documentation [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

Comment: in https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html we have "In the default configuration, options names may be abbreviated to uniqueness, case does not matter, and a single dash is sufficient, even for long option names." This clearly does not work, hence my question. So, it is all described in the documentation, true, but it doesn't work as described, also true. I could do "getopts("help|h" => \$help);" but this is not the same as described.